# Pandas calculate max for every day per id

Tags: python, pandas, max, group

I have a dataframe with three columns: ID, Date, Value reporting temperature records (Value) day by day for a month (in datetime-format) from different weather stations (ID). What I need is to 'group by' every weather station and every single day and calculate the maximum temperature for each day for each weather station in a new column.

I always only get the maximum for each weather station OR each day - but needed is the max for each weather station per day.

The table looks like that:

| Date | ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-12 22:09:35+00:00 | 1 | 18.3 |
| 2022-05-12 22:09:42+00:00 | 2 | 18.0 |

Comment: can you please add a bit more of your data to get a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? also add the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IUUC, you can do

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
out = df.groupby(['ID', df['Date'].dt.date])['Value'].max()
```

```
print(out)

ID  Date
1   2022-05-12    18.3
2   2022-05-12    18.0
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.groupby(['ID', df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')])['Value'].max()
```

```
ID  Date    
1   20220512    18.3
2   20220512    18.0
```